# Wordpress if_logged_in function on Non-wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want to somehow use this function on a non-wordpress page :

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    echo "Welcome, registered user!";
}
else {
    echo "Welcome, visitor!";
};
?>
```

Is there any way to do this? I was told it is possible if I include my wp-header.php in the Non-wordpress page, but I do not want to do this. Any other methods?

Comment: Write function is_user_logged_in(). Use sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to load the Wordpress Core into your current script. You can do it like this:

```
    //wp-admin
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php';

    //Check if someone is logged in
    global $user_level;
    get_currentuserinfo() ;
    //echo "User Level = $user_level<br>";
    if ($user_level < 1)
            die('You aren\'t allowed to view this!');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Wordpress header because that function is in the core. The only other option is to write your own function with the same name, using the same database of users.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the admin-header.php file. Just include this file:

wp-includes/pluggable.php

This file contains definition of is_current_logged_in() as well as many other user data helpers such as wp_set_current_user(), wp_get_current_user() etc.

Comment: hello, sorry I'm quite new to php and whatnot. Could you tell me exactly what I can copy/paste into my non-wp html file?

Comment: wait a minute, you want to use this function outside of WordPress?

Comment: Yes, it's on an html page that's located in the wordpress root directory, but it is not part of wordpress, juts something i made on notepad

Comment: Then iamfriendly's solution is what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Including wp-load.php is the best way to go. There are loads of ways around this, but I use something similar  to the following:

```
$wp_load_location_array = array();
$wp_load_location_array[] = "../../../../../../wp-load.php";
$wp_load_location_array[] = "../../../../../wp-load.php";
$wp_load_location_array[] = "../../../../wp-load.php";
$wp_load_location_array[] = "../../../wp-load.php";
$wp_load_location_array[] = "../../wp-load.php";

foreach($wp_load_location_array as $wp_load_location)
{
    if(file_exists($wp_load_location))
    {
        require_once($wp_load_location);
    }
}
```

It's a bit of a hack and if you actually know the location of the wp-load.php file, then you can just use that in the require_once() function.

Put that at the top of your file and you'll be able to use all of WordPress' functions in your non-wordpress page.

Comment: Why including the wp-load linke this method? Normally you know the location of the wp-load File...

Comment: Because sometimes you don't? Say you're developing a theme or plugin for others to use? If you need to load WP functions then you need to load WP. There isn't a 'neat' way to do that if you don't know where the wp-load.php file is.  You can do ajax requests without having to do this, but if you need functions such as the OP asked for, then, at the moment, this ugly way of doing things is the way forward if you're unsure of where the file is.