# Get wordpress user id from non wordpress page that is in a sub folder of wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

my wordpress site is `example.com/wordpress`
and I have a index.html in `example.com/wordpress/folder`
I want the index.html to show wordpress site current logged in user id.

I have checked this link [Wordpress if_logged_in function on Non-wordpress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665500/wordpress-if-logged-in-function-on-non-wordpress-page)
    solutions doesn't seem to work in my case

any help is appreciated
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you will need to move your code into the wordpress template files or create a custom plugin in order to access the logged in user id. If you are attempting to use an external folder for URL purposes, your best bet is to create your page within Wordpress.